# Vtk What does SetParentId() function do?

Tags: c#, c++, vtk

I want to ask about :

```
vtkRenderWindow->SetParentID(HWND);
```

What is Input ? What is Output? As far as I know the VTK creates its window as a child of the passed window (HWND).

My application uses VTK to display image. After I passed the handle for this function, i could not control mouse event on this handle.

How to control(Capture/catch) mouse events after use this function?

Thanks!